# How can I solve this error on my MovieStoreApi?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, api, asp.net-web-api

Here is my movie Model.

```
public class Movie
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string MovieName { get; set; }
        public int PublishYear { get; set; }
        public string MovieGenre { get; set; }
        public Director Director { get; set; }
        public List<Performer> Performers { get; set; }
        public double Price { get; set; }    
    }
```

Here is my Director model.

```
public class Director
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Surname { get; set; }
        public List<Movie> DirectedMovies { get; set; }

    }
```

Here is my IRepository.

```
public interface IRepository<TEntity> where TEntity : class
    {
        IEnumerable<TEntity> GetAll();
        Task<TEntity> GetById(int id);
        void Create(TEntity entity);
        Task<TEntity> Update(TEntity entity);
        Task Delete(int id);
    }
```

Here is my Repository.

```
public class Repository<TEntity> : IRepository<TEntity> where TEntity : class
    {
        private readonly ApplicationDbContext _context;
        internal DbSet<TEntity> _dbSet;
        public Repository(ApplicationDbContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
            _dbSet = _context.Set<TEntity>();
        }    
        public void Create(TEntity entity)
        {
             _context.Set<TEntity>().Add(entity);
             _context.SaveChanges();
        }    
        public IEnumerable<TEntity> GetAll()
        {
            return _context.Set<TEntity>().AsNoTracking();
        }
```

Here is my MovieRepository and IMovieRepository.

```
 public interface IMovieRepository : IRepository<Movie>
    {

    }
public class MovieRepository : Repository<Movie>, IMovieRepository
    {
        private ApplicationDbContext _context;
        public MovieRepository(ApplicationDbContext context) : base(context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }
```

Here is my MovieController.

```
public class MovieController : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly IMovieRepository _movieRepository; 
        public MovieController(IMovieRepository movie)
        {
            _movieRepository = movie;
        }
        [HttpGet]
        public async Task<IActionResult> GetMovies()
        {
           var allMovies = _movieRepository.GetAll();
           return Ok(allMovies);
        }
        [HttpPost]
        public void PostMovie(Movie movie)
        {
           _movieRepository.Create(movie); 
        }
```

When I start post operation, I get the following error:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ypkPa.png)

*What could be the reason for this ? Looking forward to your help. Thanks in advance.*

And here is my JSON Request Body.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CZVla.png)

Comment: Can you show us the JSON request body? Might be something wrong with that.

Comment: I added my JSON requestBody

Comment: Can you show the `Director` class? The error indicates that you need to specify a `"movie": // something here` in you `directedMovies` array.

Comment: I added my Director class.

Comment: The problem is the `DirectedMovies` property in your `Director` class. You shouldn't add a list of movies in your post body when defining a director. You can decorate the property with a `[JsonIgnore]` attribute, this should fix your problem.

Comment: And the best practice is to separate models that used for interacting with clients and models that used for database entities. In the other word , it's preferred to use movieDto for post method and then convert it to movie type as an entity.

Comment: none of them solved the problem.